# Definition of self adjoint matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Where does the definition of self adjoint Matrices S with the inner product come from in finite dimensional real vector spaces? I mean the following definition:
Let V be a Vector Space over the real numbers and S a quadratic Matrix acting on V. S is self adjoint iff for all v,w $\in$ V the following equation holds: $\langle Sv,w \rangle$=$\langle v,Sw\rangle$ 
What is the geometric idea from which this is derived/eg how could one come up with such a definition?